# How would I change the colours of each star in a five star rating?

Tags: html, css

So I've currently got the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="star-rating">
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1" data-color="red"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="4.0">
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.star-rating {
  line-height:32px;
  font-size:5em;
}

.star-rating .fa-star{
    color: #28a745;
}
```

Currently, no matter what star selection you click, it's always a green star. I want to make it so if you only click 1 or 2 stars, they are red. If it's three they are orange and if it's four or five they are green.
Can someone assist me with this?

Comment: use jQuery to see which start is clicked and change the color accordingly

Comment: Could you provide any code or help to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try it out I have given you a hint. based on which you can proceed furthur

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".star").click(function(){
  $var =$(this).attr("data-rating");
    $("span").css("color","#000");    
  if($var <3)
  {
    $("span").slice(0,$var).css("color","red");    
  }
  else   if($var <= 4)
  {
    $("span").slice(0,$var).css("color","yellow");
  }
  else   if($var <= 5)
  {
    $("span").slice(0,$var).css("color","green");
  }
  
  })


})
```

```css
.star-rating {
  line-height:32px;
  font-size:5em;
}

.star-rating .fa-star{
    color: #28a745;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="star-rating">
        <span class="fa fa-star-o star" data-rating="1" data-color="red"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o star" data-rating="2"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o star" data-rating="3"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o star" data-rating="4"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o star" data-rating="5"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="4.0">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using CSS and jQuery like this 
`Use this fiddle`(https://jsfiddle.net/gn7xvzm2/)

Comment: Some additional information in the answer would be appreciated.